# Custom resample function: only sample similar values hourly - Irregular time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am quite new to the game and can't seem to find an answer to my problem online.

I have an somewhat irregular time series in Python (mostly I use Pandas to work with it), which has a datetime index (roughly every 15 minutes) and multiple columns with values. I know that those values are approximatly changing every hour, but they actually don't quite match up with the index I have. It looks something like this:

```
                       Values
2019-08-27 02:15:00    91.45 
2019-08-27 02:30:00    91.44  
2019-08-27 02:45:00    91.44  
2019-08-27 03:00:00    91.43  
2019-08-27 03:15:00    91.43 
2019-08-27 03:30:00    91.43  
2019-08-27 03:45:00    91.42
```

This is just an example, but one can see that the values change at random times (:15, :45, :00) and even tho they should change every hour sometimes there are only two 15 min intervalls with values, so I can't just say: take a group of 4 values and resample them to one hour.

So my idea was to use the if and else function to create something like this: 
if a value is the same as the next one: resample those to an hour
else: add one hour to the resampled index.

How could I accomplish that in Python and does my idea even make sense??

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Please show some code of what you've tried inline with your idea in mind.

Comment: I would love to, but I have no clue how the get started and implement my idea into a code. I am really new to python and sometimes don't know what is and isn't possible. 
For example I have in mind: 
if value x = value x +1: series.resample('H') 
But then I don't think that could work because it would automaticallly resample the whole series and not only the similar values correct?

Comment: try the code I have added to the answers below. If it helps, I can explain further.

Comment: sorry for me being stupid, but how do I use your code and link it to my series/dataframe I have? If I just enter the code as is, I get a new series with 15 Min or whatever steps with values from 0 to 29 (range 30)?

Comment: Yes .. you can create a list of your own values (Ex: `my_list = [91.45, 91.44, 91.44, 91.43, 91.43, 91.43, 91.42]`) and then replace the `range(30)` with this `my_list` like `series = pd.Series(my_list, index=index)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.resample`.

Ex:

```py
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range('2019-08-27 02:15:00', periods=30, freq='15min')
series = pd.Series(range(30), index=index)

series.resample('15min').mean()
```

```
2019-08-27 02:00:00     1.0
2019-08-27 03:00:00     4.5
2019-08-27 04:00:00     8.5
2019-08-27 05:00:00    12.5
2019-08-27 06:00:00    16.5
2019-08-27 07:00:00    20.5
2019-08-27 08:00:00    24.5
2019-08-27 09:00:00    28.0
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thx for the input. Not sure if this actually helps me tho. I would still ignore the fact if the values are the same or not and would just resample them? My goal is to only resample the same values. Or I don't fully understand your approach, then I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is not Python.

When you use plain Python, you have a simple and nice procedural language and you iterate over values in containers. When you use Pandas, you should try hard to avoid any explicit Python loop at Python level. The rationale is that Pandas (and numpy for the underlying containers) uses C optimized code. So you have a large gain when using pandas and numpy tools (it is called *vectorization*).

Here what you want already exists in Pandas and is called `resample`.

In you example, and provided the index is a true DatetimeIndex (*), you just do:

```
df2 = df.resample('1H').mean()
```

It gives:

```
                        Values
2019-08-27 02:00:00  91.443333
2019-08-27 03:00:00  91.427500
```

---

(*) If not, convert it first with: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

---

From your edit, I think that you want to get one value from each period. A possible way would be to take the most frequent one in the interval H-15T H+30T.

You could then use:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.resample('60T', base=45, loffset=pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)).agg(
    lambda x: x['Values'].value_counts().index[0]).rename('Values'))
```

This one give:

```
                     Values
2019-08-27 02:00:00   91.45
2019-08-27 03:00:00   91.43
2019-08-27 04:00:00   91.42
```

Comment: thx for clarification! Yes the indes is already set to the datetime and I know how simply resampling works or is used. But as mentioned, resampling alone doesn't help me out. I need to resample only the same values. so get something like this: 

`2019-08-27 02:00:00    91.44
2019-08-27 03:00:00    91.43
2019-08-27 04:00:00    91.42`

Comment: @Biene: I cannot understand what means *resample only the same values*. What is the rationale that leads to `91.44` for `02:00:00`?

Comment: well, all the same values (repeating numbers of e.g. 91.44) belong to the same hour or could potentially be also 2 hours (if the value stays constant for a longer period of time) but I don't want to worry about that right now. And I just decided to put along 91.44 with 2:00:00. it depends on the starting point of course, I only have an example which shows a loc

Comment: @Biene You can use `first` or `last` instead of `mean` if you want to get one *random* value. I have added in my answer a way to get the most frequent value.